# jQuery: sharing function between page code and document.ready code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some nice dialogues defined as such in jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#someDialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        model: true,
        buttons: {
            "Do Something": function() {
                var cleanInput = sanitizeInput(input);
                // Do something with the clean input
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
        }
    });

    function sanitizeInput(input) {
        // Some magic here
        return input;
    }
});
</script>
```

Somewhere in the page, unrelated to the dialog, I have an element that calls a function with a parameter:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething('wendy');">Wendy's stats</a>
```

And the associated JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function doSomething(input) {
    var cleanInput = sanitizeInput(input);
    // Some code here
}

</script>
```

I would like to reuse the sanitizeInput() function for this function as well. However, from outside the document.ready function, the dialog does not work. Putting the doSomething() function inside the document.ready function breaks it likewise. So where do I put the sanitizeInput() function such that both can use it?

Thanks.

Comment: inside the ready `window.func_name = function()` to make global

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move the function outside the `ready()` callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#someDialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        model: true,
        buttons: {
            "Do Something": function() {
                var cleanInput = sanitizeInput(input);
                // Do something with the clean input
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
        }
    });
});

  /*** Make it global ***/
function sanitizeInput(input) {
    // Some magic here
    return input;
}
```

Now `sanitizeInput()` is globally available instead of confined to the variable scope of the `ready()` callback.

Comment: When the javascript is outside the document.ready function, then the code inside that function cannot use it. I have reduced this to a very simple example and tested in Firefox 7, which is one of my target browsers.

Comment: @dotancohen: That's not right. Any functions/variable outside the `ready()` callback are available inside the callback. This is how lexical scoping works. But if you did `var sanitizeInput = function(...`, then you'd need to make sure that it comes *before* your `ready()` call.

Comment: ...if it isn't working, then you'll need to include the non-working code in your question.

Comment: ...[here's a simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/6QrPN/) that demonstrates that it works.

Comment: Thanks, I see that. [Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) is an example from the jQuery UI site that does not work. Try moving the variables and following functions outside, and it breaks: updateTips(), checkLength(), checkRegexp(). Sorry that I cannot post it to the jsFiddle site (nice find, by the way!) but it includes external CSS.

Comment: @dotancohen: If you're moving them outside the `ready()`, but into a different function, then you're right, they won't work. Lexical scoping happens in JavaScript when functions are nested inside each other. So a function can look outside of itself to its enclosing environment, but it can't see inside *"sibling"* functions that are in the same environment.

Comment: ...[here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/6QrPN/1/) that shows a few functions nested in different ways. It describes which functions can see which variables.

Comment: Thank you, I actually a familiar with JS scope and I know that you are right. I will review my problem code thoroughly, and I will review your examples just in case. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, I would suggest some small changes.

First of all, I would replace this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething('wendy');">Wendy's stats</a>
```

with:

```
<a href="#" data-name="wendy or server var">Wendy's stats</a>
```

and then add this to the end of the `$(document).ready` block:

```
$("a[data-name]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomething($(this).data("name"));
});
```

Comment: Start with http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ and http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thank you Karim! I see that depends upon HTML5, I am not certain that it will work in all common current browsers but I will experiment a bit. Thanks!

Comment: @dotancohen - jQuery has fallback support for the data attribute, so you don't really have to worry about that.